# Joining/Querying Self-Referential "Grandchildren" Tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

Say I have a table as following:

countries

```
| ID    | Name    | Population | Continent |
```

Countries is self-referential, and has an association table:

alliances

```
| country_id | ally_id    |
```

I understand that I need to use the 'AS' keyword to join the table, say, as c1, c2, etc. But I can't quite wrap my head around how to go about this for grandchildren, great grandchildren, etc.

How would I write SQL, for example, to get the countries where they have an ally' who's ally's population is greater than 50 000 000?

I'm generating this SQL based off of models defined in code, so need to be able to support this kind of behaviour up to a user-defined depth.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query for your example is

```
SELECT c1.name
FROM countries AS c1
   JOIN alliances AS a ON c1.id = a.country_id
   JOIN countries AS c2 ON a.ally_id = c2.id
WHERE c2.population > 50000000;
```

If this was a homework question (and it looks like one) you have found the sucker who does it for you.

Comment: Thanks for the note. And actually no haha, it's not homework. I just used that example for explanatory purposes. I'm developing a library at work in Golang, that handles basic crud operations from user-defined data structures.